# How is distributed memory parallelism handled in Rust?

Tags: parallel-processing, rust, mpi, cluster-computing, hpc

How is distributed memory parallelism handled in Rust?  By that, I mean language constructs, libraries, or other features to handle computing on something like a cluster akin to what MPI provides C, but not necessarily using the same primitives or methodology.  In the Rustonomicon, I see a discussion of threads and concurrency, but I don't see any discussion on parallelizing across multiple computers.

Answer (score 7):

To the best of my knowledge, there isn't really anything built into the language for distributed computing (which is understandable, since that's arguably not really the language's major focus, or at least wasn't back in the day).  I don't believe there's any particularly popular crate or another for distributed computing either.  [Actix](https://crates.io/crates/actix) is probably the only actor crate that has achieved any traction, and it supports HTTP, but I don't think it is targeted at HPC/supercomputer setups.  You also definitely would want to check out [Tokio](https://tokio.rs), which seems to be pretty much *the* library for asynchronous programming in Rust, and is specifically targeted towards network IO operations.

At the present point in time, if you're looking to replicate MPI, my guess would be that your best bet is to use FFI to a C-based MPI library.  It appears that there's been [a handful of attempts](https://crates.io/search?q=mpi) to create bindings to MPI for Rust, but I'm not sure that any of them are particularly complete.

Comment: *which is understandable, since that's arguably not really the language's major focus, or at least wasn't back in the day* => I would rather say that distributed computing is more of a library concern than a language concern; if the language has good support for parallel execution (multi-threading), then distributed computing can be built on top. As for libraries for distributed computing: [CityBound](https://github.com/citybound/citybound) features a really neat actor system which distributes the computing cost across all players (and hosts) involved.